# External Hard Drive Won't Format - Set to GPT/RAW

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, diskpart

I'm  trying to format an external hard drive, preferably to exFAT, but nothing is working.

If I check the details of the disk in diskpart, I get this:

[image: screnshot shot of diskpart]

And, this is what it looks like in disk management:

[image: screenshot of disk management]

But, I get an error message if I try anything in diskmanagent, and when I try to clean the disk in diskpart I get:

`DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check). See the System Event Log for more information.`

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Did you `chkdsk /r` it? What did the System Event Log say? A cyclic redundancy check (CRC) error indicates drive failure, if that drive was purchased recently, you should return that drive and get a replacement under warranty.

Comment: You should do what has been suggested in the previous comment although in all likelihood the drive is defective and not fixable.

Comment: I don't think I can `chkdsk /r` because the drive doesn't have a drive letter, and I don't really know how the system event log works. I haven't really used it much.

Comment: But do you have warranty?

Comment: No, it was second hand.

Comment: Is there any important data on it?

Comment: No, there's no data on it.

Comment: Ok then you are lucky. I wouldn't bother trying to fix it because I wouldn't trust it and I would simply buy a new drive (if that is an option). CRC errors are bad news usually so you are lucky there is no important data on it. And 1tb drives are not very expensive nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @Gatendo but that really doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: I would never recommend that if I didn't believe it was the best option (even for people who are not as rich as I am). Even if you can get the drive to work, a CRC error means it is dying. And in my experience, it won't take long. I wouldn't want you to lose data, which is often worse than spending some money. If you live in the Netherlands I will happily send you a free used 2TB drive. Which country do you live in? I may be able to help you.

Comment: How much would a decent 1tb second hand hard drive be in AUD? I may live life from a western European perspective, but I've seen some documentaries and I've travelled a bit.

Comment: Including shipping of course.

Comment: @tdrsam Is there a way I can contact you outside of this website?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a third-party tool such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), rather than discarding the drive. First, remove all partitions and commit (save). Second, create a single partition and commit. Finally, format that partition as you wish. BTW, exFAT, while it can have files >4GB, might not be suitable as a boot partition, and non-MS operating systems may need *fuse* or other software to use exFAT.

If that does not work, an HDD contains spiffy rare-earth magnets, and the platter can be used as a reflector.

Comment: Good point, those magnets are fun. Here a tutorial on how to get them out: https://youtu.be/uSjxLH7vWUM?t=51 Be careful, they can break in to very sharp shards.

Comment: And keep them far from credit cards that still have mag tape strip.

Comment: @drmoishePippik Thanks for trying, but DiskGenius wasn't able to do anything with it either. I'll try the second option.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to perform a low level format on the drive, usually the manufacturer will offer special low level format tools on their website.

Comment: With CRC errors? No, not really.

Comment: According to the screenshot above its an Iomega branded disk. "*Formerly a public company, it was acquired by EMC Corporation in 2008, and then by Lenovo, which rebranded the product line as LenovoEMC, until discontinuation in 2018.*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iomega Their website is dead (like the disk)